# Mac Chrome hover events behave differently when window is maximised

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, macos, google-chrome

A web page I am developing has mouse over events (both css and javascript) for a top navigation bar. It works fine when the browser window is floating, but when maximized (full screen) the hover classes have no effect anymore. It begins to act like a tablet display, I must point and click for my hover actions to take effect. I achieve the events when I click, but mouse hover changes my cursor to a text select cursor.

This does not happen on a windows computer

As a matter of fact, this behaviour is good if it is meant to support tablets but I'd appreciate if anybody could let me know if this is a bug or intended?

Comment: That doesn't sound like an intended effect. It seems more like a bug. Do you have a jsfiddle link, with a code example in it? Or a link to your website, if it's online?

Comment: Yeah, sorry it is a bit corwdy..  http://urlgone.com/4db6c9/

Comment: Actually, when I reload the page when maximized, it gets back to normal, so I could fix it by listening & refreshing upon resize

Answer (score 7):

This is a 3+ year old unfixed bug in Chromium.

http://crbug.com/170058